# The equation of a straight line

Tags: proof-verification, analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the straight line passing through the point $(3 , -1 ,0)$ and intersects the straight line $r=(2,1,1) + t(1,2,-1)$ orthogonally.

Since the two straight lines are intersecting orthogonally, their direction vectors are perpendicular

$$d_1 = (1,2,-1) , d_2 = (a ,b ,c) $$

$$d_1\cdot d_2 = 0 = a +2b -c $$

Let $a=b = 1$, then $c = 3 , d_2 = (1,1,3)$

Then the required equation is $r = (3,-1 ,0) + t(1,1,3)$
Is my solution correct ?

Comment: Check:  do your lines intersect?

Comment: I agree WLOG you can set $a = 1$, but how can you set $b = a = 1$? What is your justification for this leap?

Comment: any triplet $(a,b,c) $ satisfies the equation $a+2b-c = 0$ is a direction vector for the required straight line , we can check that the vector i have picked up is perpendicular to the direction vector of the given straight line @bounceback

Comment: Are you sure? How could (1,0,1) and (0,1,2), say, both be direction vectors of the same line?

Comment: Where did you get the vectors $(1,0,1) , (0,1,2)$ from ? @bounceback

Comment: Is there more than one line passes through the given point and perpendicular to the given line ? @J.W.Tanner 9

Comment: They both satisfy $a + 2b - c = 0$

Comment: It is confusing that you use the same symbol $r$ for two different lines

Comment: @HussienMohamed:  yes, a whole plane does; see my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are many lines containing the point $(3,-1,0)$ with direction vector perpendicular to $(1,2,-1)$

-- they are in a plane -- but you need one that intersects the given line,

and the one you found does not.

As you correctly indicated, the direction perpendicular to $(1,2,-1)$ is $(a,b,c)$, with $a+2b-c=0$.

It is fine to scale $(a\,',b\,',c\,')$ to $(1,b,c)$, but you were incorrect to set $b=1$ too.

So we need the line $(2,1,1)+t(1,2,-1)$ to intersect $(3,-1,0)+s(1,b,c)$.

Equating components yields   equations $2+t=3+s, 1+2t=-1+sb,$ and $ 1-t=sc$.

We also have $1+2b-c=0$.

Solving these four equations in four unknowns (details available upon request) yields $t=-\dfrac13$, $s=-\dfrac43$, and $b=c=-1$.  Thus, the desired line is $(3,-1,0)+s(1,-1,-1);$

it intersects the other line when $s=-\dfrac43$.

Comment: I am confusing with the concept that  there are many lines pass through the same point and have the same direction vector ? Is not this a contradiction with Euclidean parallel axiom which says that there is a unique line passes through a given point and parallel to a given line ? ! @J.W.Tanner

Comment: There is a unique line through a point parallel to a given line, but in $3$ dimensions there is a whole plane containing a point and lines perpendicular to a given direction; your line and my line are both perpendicular to $(1,2,-1)$, but only mine intersects the line given by $(2,1,1)+t(1,2,-1)$

Answer (score 0):

The (unnormalized) vector from your fixed point to a candidate point on the line, ${\bf v}_1 (t)$ is:

$${\bf v}_1(t) = (3,-1,0) - \left( (2,1,1) + t(1,2,-1)\right)$$

The (unnormalized) vector of the line is just the difference of its end points:

$${\bf v}_2 = \left( (2,1,1) - (1,2,-1) \right) = (1,-1,0)$$

Set the dot product to zero, i.e., ${\bf v}_1(t) \cdot {\bf v}_2$:

$$(1,-1,0) \cdot (1,-2,-1) + (1, -1,0) \cdot t (1,2,-1) = 0$$

Solve to find $t=3$.  Then plug in to find the point.

Comment: Nice approach, but isn't $\mathbf v_1(t)=(1,-2,-1)\color{red}-t(1,2,-1)$ and $\mathbf v_2=(1,2,-1)$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If the lines are to meet orthogonally, they meet at the point on $r_1(t) = (2,1,1) + t(1,2,-1)$ closest to $(3,-1,0)$. So your first task is to minimise the distance between the point and the line. That is, minimise
$$\sqrt{(-1+t)^2+(2+2t)^2+(1-t)^2}.$$
(You might as well ignore the square root, and if you know calculus it should help you find the minimum.)
Once you have the value of $t$, plug it into $r_1(t)$ to find the desired intersection point.
Once you have that you can set any $s \neq 0$ you like in $r_2(s) = (3,-1,0) + s(a,b,c)$ and solve for $a,b,c$, scale it if you like. Check that $a + 2b - c = 0$ like you suggested. If so, and the lines do indeed intersect, you have it.

Comment: We have just one straight line that passes through the given point and perpendicular to the given straight line but this straight line is not necessary meet the given line so the two straight lines may be perpendicular but not intersecting @bounceback

Comment: Could you please restate the question? It seems to me they are. There is a grammatical error (at 'and intersects') in 'Find the equation of the straight line passing through the point (3,−1,0) and intersects the straight line r=(2,1,1)+t(1,2,−1) orthogonally.'